# CRC32 with signed bytes in java

Tags: java, c, crc32

I am trying to convert a C CRC32 code to java. The below code is what I came up with. But it seems to work differently. The expected CRC32 calculated in C is 13 82 D8 46) but the output for the below code is   " the final crc is -2084771805  in hex ffffffff83bce823". Can someone tell me why?

C code

```
uint32 crc32_update(uint32 crc, const uint8_t *data, uint16 data_len)
{

uint16_t tbl_idx;

while (data_len--) {
    tbl_idx = crc ^ (*data >> (0 * 4));
    crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >> 4);
    tbl_idx = crc ^ (*data >> (1 * 4));
    crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >> 4);

    data++;
}
return crc & 0xffffffff;
}
```

JAVA code.

```
public class crc32trial_3 {


static  final  long crc_table[] = new long[] {
    0x00000000, 0x1db71064, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x26d930ac,
    0x76dc4190, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x4db26158, 0x5005713c,
    0xedb88320, 0xf00f9344, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xcb61b38c,
    0x9b64c2b0, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xa00ae278, 0xbdbdf21c
};



public static long crc32_init()
{
    return 0xffffffff;
}

private static  long crc32_update(long crc, byte[] data, int data_len)
 {
     int tbl_idx;

    for(int i = 0 ; i <  data_len ; i ++) {
         tbl_idx = (int)crc ^ (data[i] >> (0 * 4));
         crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >> 4);
         tbl_idx = (int)crc ^ (data[i] >> (1 * 4));
         crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >> 4);

         //data++;
     }

     return crc & 0xffffffff;

 }



 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     long intialcrc = crc32_init();
     long crc;


     System.out.println("the intail crc = " + intialcrc);
     byte[] packets = new byte[]{ 88,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-56,-46,-117,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,-68,118 };

     byte[] totalLenght = new byte[]{100,0,0,0};
     byte[] totalSettingBlock = new byte[]{2};
      crc = crc32_update(intialcrc,totalLenght,4);
      crc = crc32_update(crc, totalSettingBlock,1);
      int temp = 28 + 72;
      crc = crc32_update(crc,packets, temp);
      long finalcrc = crc;




     System.out.println(" the final crc is " + finalcrc + "  in hex " +  Long.toHexString(finalcrc));

 }


}
```

Comment: [`java.util.zip.CRC32`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html) does exist. And [the code is available](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/zip/CRC32.java#CRC32), too.

Comment: And shifting right by 0*4 does nohing. Have you mis-copied your source?

Comment: I tried but crc.reset () sets the intial value to 0 however I require it to be -1.

Comment: The expected CRC of what exactly should be 13 82 D8 46?  How did you determine what it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "L" at the end of all of your hex constants.  Then I get `46d81382` as the result, which is close to, but a permutation of what you said is expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `>>` operator in C and in Java are not exactly the same thing. The >> in Java is only defined for the type int and long, and its *always* a signed shift, opposed to C where it is unsigned if the left hand expression is unsigned the shift is unsigned. The usigned shift operator in Java is `>>>`. So when translating C's `usigned >> n`, in Java it becomes `signed >>> n`.

Second, since >> (and >>>) exists *only* for int and long in Java, in an expression like `(byte) >> 4` the byte undergoes a widening conversion to int *first*, And as byte is signed it means *sign extension* to int, whereas in C bytes are unsigned meaning their widening conversion is unsigned too. So if the byte is to be treated as unsigned, it must be explicitly converted into an unsigned int (commonly called byte masking): `int usigned = (byte expression) & 0xFF;`.

And I have no idea *why* you chose to declare CRC and table as *long*, where *int* would perfectly suffice.

Changing the code accordingly gives:

```
public class crctrial3 {

    static final int crc_table[] = new int[] { 0x00000000, 0x1db71064,
            0x3b6e20c8, 0x26d930ac, 0x76dc4190, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x4db26158,
            0x5005713c, 0xedb88320, 0xf00f9344, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xcb61b38c,
            0x9b64c2b0, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xa00ae278, 0xbdbdf21c };

    public static int crc32_init() {
        return 0xffffffff;
    }

    private static int crc32_update(int crc, byte[] data, int data_len) {
        int tbl_idx;

        for (int i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
            // proper byte masking and shift semantics
            tbl_idx = crc ^ ((data[i] & 0xFF) >>> (0 * 4));
            crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >>> 4);
            tbl_idx = (int) crc ^ ((data[i] & 0xFF) >>> (1 * 4));
            crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >>> 4);

            // data++;
        }

        return crc & 0xffffffff;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int intialcrc = crc32_init();
        int crc;

        System.out.println("the intail crc = " + intialcrc);
        byte[] packets = new byte[] { 88, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -56, -46, -117,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -68, 118 };

        byte[] totalLenght = new byte[] { 100, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte[] totalSettingBlock = new byte[] { 2 };
        crc = crc32_update(intialcrc, totalLenght, 4);
        crc = crc32_update(crc, totalSettingBlock, 1);
        int temp = 28 + 72;
        crc = crc32_update(crc, packets, temp);
        int finalcrc = crc;

        System.out.println(" the final crc is " + finalcrc + "  in hex "
                + Integer.toHexString(finalcrc));

    }

}
```

And running it gives:

`the intail crc = -1
 the final crc is 1188565890  in hex 46d81382`

Looks like there is a mismatch in the byte order, without knowing the code you used to arrive at your 13 82 D8 46 there is no way of telling where the problem lies. Since 13 82 D8 46 is not a simple byte order reversal of 46 D8 13 82 I suspect you originally simply *misread or mistyped* it.

Comment: The `>>>` for `tbl_idx` can just as well be the original `>>`, since the index is `& 0x0f`ed.  If you use `int`s instead of `long`s, then indeed `>>>` is necessary in `crc >>> 4`.  The minimal change to the code in my answer is simply to make all the constants long and leaving the variables long, which avoids ever having to worry about signed shifts messing things up.  Then you also don't need the `& 0xffffffff` on the returned `crc`.

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes, you're absolutely right; it can be made work with your minimal change. I just went through the code mechanically (call it peephole translation). The crc & 0xffffffff is a leftover from the original code which I *should* have deleted, but simply didn't notice. Since I changed the declaration of crc to int it, it does nothing anymore.